# Passar objeto como parâmetro no onClick em Typescript

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Estou com uma dificuldade e gostaria de pedir ajuda de vocês, estou tentando passar um objeto (botão) como parâmetro para uma função no React usando typescript e estou recebendo um erro.

```
<button id='teste' name='teste' type='button' value='teste' onClick={facaAlgo(this)}>botao teste</button>
```

isso me retorna o seguinte erro:

> "O tipo 'void' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo
> 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.ts(2322)
> index.d.ts(1480, 9): O tipo esperado vem da propriedade 'onClick', que
> é declarada aqui no tipo
> 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes,
> HTMLButtonElement>'"

Em JavaScript o mesmo não acontece se eu fizer exatamente este exemplo citado acima, consigo dentro da função acessar as propriedades como `id`, `name` e `value` do botão. Alguém consegue me explicar onde estou errando?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, amigo, tudo bem?

Como o TS é mais tipado, esse tipo de erro vai acontecer.

O que ocorre é que o onclick espera uma função com retorno. Tente mudar o retorno da sua função facaAlgo() para boolean e retornar "true" quando efetua as operações e false quando dá algum erro.

```
function facaAlgo(): Boolean {
    if(<fez_o_q_devia_fazer>) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Veja se dessa forma, funciona.

Espero ter ajudado. :D

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo pelo auxilio, acredito que desta forma funcione sim pois o erro era referente a tipagem. Acabou que não vou mais precisar implementar desta forma, mas agradeço muito sua ajuda tenha um bom dia